# Disposing managed resources in WPF Custom Controls

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, disposing

I'm writing some WPF custom controls for a third part library. For instance I enhanced the standard `ComboBox` with some dependency properties. The main problem is that my controls have as private instances some `IDisposable` objects, and I'd like to dispose these objects. 
The structure of my controls is something like this :

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox

{

private IDisposableObject _innerObject;   
[..]

}
```

How can I ensure this object is disposed when the control is GC'ed and what is the best way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:** I tried with the `Finalizer` method, but I think that it's not a clean and good solution, and with the `Unloaded` event of the control (that it's raised also when the themes changes).

Answer (score 0):

Have your MyComboBox Implement IDisposable and in that dispose menthod dispose of your other objects.
When you are done with your combo box call dispose on it.

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox, IDisposable 
{ 

    private IDisposableObject _innerObject;    
    [..] 

    public void  Dispose()
    {
        _innerObject.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The problem is that the ComboBox belongs to a control library, that tipically it's used only within XAML code. So the Dispose method is not called.